# How to pass the endless verifying status on iMessage or FaceTime activation when phone number is wrong?

Tags: iphone, messages, facetime, verify

My iMessage continues to show `Verifing` status on iPhone 4S (iOS 5.1).

- The phone number displayed at iMessage verifing screen is wrong (old one)
- The Settings > Phone displays the correct number
- iTunes shows correct number
- The phone can successfully send or receive SMS messages

I already tried the accepted answer from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3401647?start=0&tstart=0 but it does not work.

Comment: I know this is simple, but have you tried simply disabling, then enabling iMessage?  That worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a common problem that can be solved by turning off and on `iMessages`. You may want to wait a little bit between these operations.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you changed phones/data plans and restored your iPhone from backup?

The only time I encountered quite important problems with my iPhone's setup was when I made a backup (in iTunes) sold my iPhone (3G) flew to a new country bought a new iPhone (4) with a new provider and setup the new iPhone by restoring restoring from backup. From that point my network settings went bad and I experienced numerous issues (visual voicemail, FaceTime and internet access were not working properly or at all).

To solve the problem I had to restore the iPhone and then setup the iPhone as a new iPhone. It was the only thing that worked for me. You could try that.